# File not found when using gspread import_csv function in python

Tags: python, google-api, gspread

I am using gspread package in python.

I try to import a csv into a google spreadsheet but I got an error.

My code is as follows:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

spreadsheet_id = '1tFhK2-zebkG1fZFF6Xe5LHyONkh97ANOkcf'

scopes = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('./credentials.json', scopes=scopes)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

file = open('test_csv.csv',mode='r')
csv = file.read()
file.close()

client.import_csv(spreadsheet_id, csv)
```

The error I got is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
APIError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-264-eb5d4ce7bc69> in <module>()
----> 1 client.import_csv(spreadsheet_id, csv)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py in import_csv(self, file_id, data)
    238                 'convert': True
    239             },
--> 240             headers=headers
    241         )
    242 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py in request(self, method, endpoint, params, data, json, files, headers)
     77             return response
     78         else:
---> 79             raise APIError(response)
     80 
     81     def list_spreadsheet_files(self):

APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: 1tFhK2-zebkG1fZFF6Xe5LHyONkh97ANOkcf",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "file"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: 1tFhK2-zebkG1fZFF6Xe5LHyONkh97ANOkcf"
 }
}
```

However, I get no error when I try to read or write on cell directly (with `update_cell` function for example), so the spreadsheet does exist and I can write on it. It is specifically `import_csv` that throws an error.

I have created the google sheet through the google drive web interface. I then added my client_email from credential.json (blabla@blabla-220209.iam.gserviceaccount.com) in the authorized mail of the spreadsheet.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Could you try to create a new spreadsheet with [gc.create](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.Client.create) and import it there? You may then share the spreadsheet with yourself with [gc.insert_permission](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.Client.insert_permission)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by sharing the file with the 'client_email' found within the credentials JSON file. Although I did not test this, I also suspect making the spreadsheet Public (anyone on web can see) will fix the issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> By going to your sheet and changing sharing options to anyone with the
> link can edit, fixes it.

*Here's the code I used:*

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ["(some scopes)"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
gc = gspread.service_account("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sLink = "(link)"
sh = gc.open_by_url(sLink)
sh.share('<example.email.com>', perm_type='user', role='writer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest version of gspread. The one that is e.g. bundled with Google Colab is outdated:

`!pip install --upgrade gspread`

This fixed the error in `gs.csv_import` for me.