# Google API service account authentication can't find JSON credentials file

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I can't get the Google API to find my service account's credentials. I downloaded the necessary JSON file with the right name into the proper place, and I'm using Python code straight off the API documentation:

```
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account()

sh = gc.open("Example spreadsheet (I'll replace this with my actual sheet name later)")

print(sh.sheet1.get('A1'))
```

The code stops at `gc = gspread.service_account()` with a `FileNotFoundError`. I discovered via an error message that this is because it's looking at the complete wrong file path (I think it's thinking I'm on a Mac when I'm actually on a Windows PC??). Overriding the file name, i.e.

`gc = gspread.service_account(filename="insert\actual\path\here.json")`,

does not work either, which is the mystifying part. I copied that path straight out of my file explorer, doubled the backslashes so Unicode doesn't try to escape it all (that happened once), tried every modification on the file path I could think of (`%APPDATA%\gspread\service_account.json` instead of the whole thing, etc.) - what could be going wrong?

Edit: @mods, feel free to close the question! I found the issue, which is that I was using the Repl.it online coding environment instead of a local one. I ported everything over to IDLE and it worked fine. I strongly suspect Repl.it just couldn't access my local files at all (I also tried it on Repl.it with a random screenshot in a different place, and it threw the same error).

Comment: You can try the answers on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932534/file-not-found-when-using-gspread-import-csv-function-in-python

Comment: Also, for additional reference when using gspread service_accounts(). https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account

Comment: @Jason I think the first thread you linked is outdated? I think I saw a different thread referencing that code as an older version of what I'm trying to use, unless it still works and I'm dumb lol